Waiting for React to connect... React DevTools do not connect to Expo React Native App
Problem
I want to use the regular React DevTools (and NOT the browser extension) for debugging a default React Native App with an Android Virtual Device (AVD) or iOS Emulator on a MacBook Pro.
The React DevTools open automatically and show a message

Waiting for React to connect...

but nothing happens.
I cannot find any information on how exactly to get them started.
Is it necessary to perform a special command?

How to reproduce the problem

Open default React Native App in Visual Studio Code.
Run npm start in the VS Code Terminal
Press a - open Android Virtual Device
Open a separate VS Code Terminal and run react-devtools

The React DevTools open, but only show the message Waiting for React to connect... and nothing ever happens.

There are at least 2 ways to fix this:
By Correct Order
Open the React DevTools first, then open the Android Virtual Device (AVD). Starting the AVD/Emulator will trigger the React DevTools to automatically connect to it.
By Command
If you opened the React DevTools first. Start your AVD/Emulator and open the Developer Menu on the Emulator/AVD by:

either pressing m in the Visual Studio Code Terminal (after opening your Emulator/AVD)
or cmd+m on your Android AVD OR cmd-d on your iOS Emulator

then tap "Reload" which will restart the App on the AVD/Emluator and automatically connect it to the already opened React DevTools.

